# Почему ошибка?я новичек и только начал изучать react и вк апи

Tags: javascript, reactjs, вконтакте, vk-mini-apps

вот отрывок кода где выдаёт ошибку

```
const storageData = await bridge.send('VKWebAppStorageGet', props:{
    keys: Object.values(STORAGE_KEYS)
});
```

вот сама ошибка

```
SyntaxError: C:\Users\megat\minini\src\App.js: Unexpected token (35:23)

  33 |          const user = await bridge.send('VKWebAppGetUserInfo');
  34 |          const storageData = await bridge.send('VKWebAppStorageGet', props:{
> 35 |              keys: Object.values(STORAGE_KEYS)
     |                                 ^
  36 |          });
  37 |          console.log(storageData)
  38 |          setUser(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае использован неверный синтаксис при передаче параметра

```
await bridge.send('VKWebAppStorageGet', props:{
```

В данном месте лишняя часть `props:`.

Для решения, достаточно убрать ее.